# "Read More" button appears on every post in blogger

Tags: html, themes, blogger

I've been trying to remove the "Read More" button that appears at every single post, which includes the posts that I didn't put jumplink on. Have been searching for a while but still to no avail.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Just add some CSS to hide it!

1. Go to the themes section on your blogger homepage.
2. Click Edit HTML
3. Find (Use Ctrl+F) **]]></b:skin>** and the following CSS just before it.

```css
.jump-link.flat-button.ripple{display:none;}
```

If this doesn't help, contact me.